# Windows 10 universal app where did TriggerAction<T> go?

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Im trying to port some code form a old windows phone project but im having 2 problems.

Where did the `TriggerAction<T>` class go? i can find `Windows.UI.Xaml.TriggerAction` but there is no `Invoke` method to overload also the `AssociatedObject` is missing..

Secondly how do i use the `EventTrigger.RoutedEvent` im trying to wire it up to `KeyUp` but no matter what i write i get `The event 'KeyUp' is not a RoutedEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can replace them with Binding Command and Behavior SDK.
[Here](http://blog.falafel.com/windows-10-development-mvvmlight-navigationservice-and-the-behaviors-sdk/) is a tutorial step-by-step to use them in MVVM-Light